# Get parent path from another module

Tags: angular

I want to get the path of the state which I navigated to current path. 
And I want to take it even if I navigated from one module to another one. 
Is it possible to do it in Angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with it?
If you just want to save the state data to go back and forth through states without losing it, that might do the trick

```
let data = {}; localStorage.setItem('yourStateData', data);
```